# Вместо одного запроса отправляется два Ajax, Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

4.16.4 версия моего Express 
Первый объект приходит пустым, а второй нормальным.
Сервер

```
app.use('/javascripts',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules','jquery','dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.post('/registration',(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body);
 const login=req.body.login;
 const password=req.body.password;
 const passwordConfirm=req.body.passwordConfirm;
 console.log(login);

 if(login.length==0 || password.length==0 || passwordConfirm.length==0){
    res.json({
        ok:false,
        error:'Все поля должны быть заполнены!',
        fields:['login','password','passwordConfirmd']
    }) }else if (login.length<3 || login.length>16){
        res.json({
            ok:false,
            error:'Длина логина от 3 до 16 символов!',
            fields:['login']
        });}
        else if(password!==passwordConfirm){
            res.json({
                ok:false,
                error:'Пароли не совпадают',
                fields:['password','passwordConfirm']
            })
        }
         else {
            var v=String(login);
            db.query("SELECT count(title) FROM posts WHERE title=$1;",[v]).then(function(ress){

                if(ress.rows[0].count==0){
                        bcrypt.hash(password,null,null,function(err,hash){

                db.query("INSERT INTO posts (id,title, body) VALUES (nextval('serial'),$1,$2 );", [login,hash]);

            }) 
                } else {
                    res.json({
                ok:false,
                error:'Логин занят',
                fields:['login']
            });

                }

                                })


         }
    });
```

Ниже код страницы

```
 $(function(){
    $('.register-button').click(function(){
        var data={
            login:$('#register-login').val(),
            password:$('#register-password').val(),
            passwordConfirm:$('#register-password-confirm').val()
        };
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType:'application/json',
            url:'/registration'

        }).done(function(data){
            if(!data.ok){
                $('.register h2').after(data.error)
            }
        })
    });


    })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90390/discussion-on-question-by-danythere------ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии `4.16` в express добавлен встроенный middleware для обработки json запросов: [`express.json([options])`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json)

Нужно просто добавить данный middleware по аналогии с уже используемыми, например:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

---

Проблема двойного запроса заключается в том, что первый это ajax запрос, для которого не было добавлено парсера тела поэтому результат приходил пустой, а второй - это прямая отправка формы, для которой парсер тела был добавлен `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));`.

Для решения достаточно запретить форме делать `submit`, например добавив в обработчике `onsubmit` вызов [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка пропала! app.use(express.json()); помогло

Comment: @danythere, а количество запросов так и осталось два?

Comment: К сожалению почему-то да. При первом запросе пользователь добавляется в БД, а при втором уже пишет, что логин занят и крашится все

Comment: У формы регистрации стоит метод пост. Из-за него не может быть?

Comment: Да, было из-за метода пост в форме...

Comment: @danythere, тогда это проблема клиента. И все зависит от типа элемента с классом `register-button`. Если это <button> или <input type="submit"> - то будет выполняться отправка формы, что ты и принимаешь за второй запрос. Чтобы этого не происходило можно добавить в обработчик параметр `e`: `$('.register-button').click(function(e){` и вызвать `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @danythere, обновил ответ.

Comment: Помогло e.preventDefaulf(). Спасибо огромное. В чате почему-то не получается вам ответить.

Comment: @danythere, недостаточно репутации скорее всего :-) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3433/186999

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к комментариям:
Обработчик на сервере выглядит вот так:

```
app.post('/registration', (req,res) => {
// вот это и есть та точка, куда приходит ваш запрос.
});
```

Но, по скольку у вас post запрос, вам необходимо его распарсить через bodyParse.

А чтобы понимать как это работает, учите по книгам.

Comment: Выше мне сказали, что это тоже запрос и получится, что у меня два запроса.

Comment: $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType:'application/json',
        url:'/registration'
        })


Вот этот код у вас в браузерном скрипте. А тот который я указал, должен находиться в Express, тобишь на сервере.

А еще лучше, подробней опишите, что вы делаете. А то трудно догадаться, что вы хотите сделать, и как вы это делаете конкретно..

Comment: Так почему получается, что два запроса, если только ajax запрос, а app.post это обработчик как вы сказали

Comment: Т.к. вы не дали никакой информации дополнительной, начнем по другому.
1. У вас есть первый скрипт, который $.ajax(...), он находится в скрипте на странице. Так?
2. У вас есть сервер, реализованный на Node.js с фреймворком Express.js, так?

Comment: @danythere, _Выше мне сказали, что это тоже запрос и получится, что у меня два запроса._ - просто никто не понял, что это код сервера. Раздели их на два блока кода, чтобы видно было что это не две строки подряд

Comment: Извините... Не очень получилось)  Есть ajax в скрипте страницы, есть сервер на Node.js с Express.js. Хочу данные обработать на сервере и вернуть json обратно в код страницы, чтобы сообщить пользователю об ошибках в его данных, если таковые есть. Если нет, то просто заношу данные в бд

Comment: @danythere, **app.post('/registration',(req,res)=>** Вот это у вас где находиться, в браузерном скрипте или на сервере, в express'e ?

Comment: На сервере, выше обновил код

Comment: @danythere, через отладчик в браузере просмотрите содержимое первого запроса, кто его инициализирует, и второй точно так же. Может быть у вас где-то иной скрипт срабатывает?
Проследите, оба запроса появляются именно в момент отправки этого ajax  запроса, или она разнесены во времени?